# How to solve TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I am running this code:

```
d2 = whois.whois('sportswithamission.com')
```

It works.

Then I am converting dictionary from output into a dataframe using next code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2, orient='index')
```

This code is throwing next error:

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

How can I solve it?

Comment: Which of these two lines causes the error? Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: What is `whois`? The "standard" `whois` module does not have method `whois`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find `whois.whois` but this worked for me;

```
import whois, pandas 

domain = whois.query('sportswithamission.com')

dic = domain.__dict__

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index')
```

Ouput;

```
                                                                 0
name                                        sportswithamission.com
registrar                                         GoDaddy.com, LLC
creation_date                                  2020-03-27 11:26:20
expiration_date                                2021-03-27 11:26:20
last_updated                                                  None
status           clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#c...
name_servers      {ns12.domaincontrol.com, ns11.domaincontrol.com}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is working as well:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([d2.keys(), d2.values()]).T
```